# Serialize array into $_POST over and over

Tags: php, arrays, serialization

I'm practicing building a blackjack game and I'm stuck with being able to hit twice.  Here's my code:

```
if (empty($_POST)) {
  for ($i=0; $i<2; $i++) {
    $pHand[] = array_shift($deck);
    $dHand[] = array_shift($deck);
  }
  $deck2 = serialize($deck);
  $pHand2 = serialize($pHand);
  $dHand2 = serialize($dHand);
}


elseif ($_POST['hit'] == "Hit") {
  $deck = unserialize($_POST['deck']);
  $pHand = unserialize($_POST['pHand']);
  $dHand = unserialize($_POST['dHand']);
  $pHand[] = array_shift($deck);
  $deck2 = serialize($pHand);
  $pHand2 = serialize($dHand);
  $dHand2 = serialize($deck);
}


<form method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="pHand" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($pHand2, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="dHand" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($dHand2, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="deck" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($deck2, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>">
```

This all works great but if I press "Hit" again, my $pHand array changes into something completely different.  How do I keep the same value from the first "Hit" so that it can be added onto the 2nd, 3rd etc. "Hit"?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using $_SESSION to store the data server side between submissions instead.

Something along the lines of:

```
<?php
session_start();

if (empty($_POST)) 
{
  for ($i=0; $i<2; $i++) 
  {
    $pHand[] = array_shift($deck);
    $dHand[] = array_shift($deck);
  }

  $_SESSION['deck']  = $deck;
  $_SESSION['pHand'] = $pHand;
  $_SESSION['dHand'] = $dHand;
}
elseif ($_POST['hit'] == "Hit") 
{
  $deck    = $_SESSION['deck'];
  $pHand   = $_SESSION['pHand'];
  $dHand   = $_SESSION['dHand'];
  $pHand[] = array_shift($deck);
  $_SESSION['deck']  = $deck;
  $_SESSION['pHand'] = $pHand;
  $_SESSION['dHand'] = $dHand;
}
```

Comment: I've tried this but the problem with it is if I press "Hit" twice, the sessions will have too many arrays added on.

Comment: Sorry the code was not meant to work "out of the box". Please think of $_SESSION superglobal variable as your variable that's available between requests (as long as you call session_start() on beginning of each).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I've already played around with session and was still stuck.  I'll keep trying